# Possible to access the old value in Angular 16's effect() function (similar to Vue.js watch)?

Tags: angular, angular-signals

In Vue.js, the `watch` function gets the [new and old watched value passed as arguments](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html), which is really helpful in case the differences matter, or when I want to release the previous allocated resource.

Now in Angular 16, we finally have `signal`, `computed`, and `effect`. `effect()` seems to be the equivalent of the watch in Vue.js. But is it there also possible to get access to the old value?

The Angular [API docs](https://angular.io/api/core/effect) only mention [`onCleanup`](https://angular.io/guide/signals#effect-cleanup-functions). As `effect` does not operate on an expression as in Vue, it might not be possible to store a previous value in a generic way.

Is there a workaround?

Comment: In Angular you have full access to rxjs operators. I imagine you can use [pairwise](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/pairwise) with all the changes related to observables (forms, httpClient, ..)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Effect does not give an old value, as signals only store the current value. Angular shipped an rxjs interop package, `@angular/core/rxjs-interop`, which help you for this kind of usecase. You can use the `toObservable` function as follows to achieve what you want:

```js
/**
  * Signal version of count
  */
count = signal(0);

/**
  * Straight conversion to observable
  */
count$ = toObservable(this.count);

/**
  * Pairwise conversion to achieve old/new functionality
  */
countPrevAndCurr$ = this.count$.pipe(
  pairwise(),
  map(([oldVal, newVal]) => {
    console.log('Old Value (Observable): ', oldVal);
    console.log('New Value (Observable): ', newVal);
    return { old: oldVal, new: newVal };
  })
);
```

Here is a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gaiwmm?file=src/main.ts) showing the functionality in action.

**Note:** At the time of writing this answer both the Angular Signals and Rxjs Interop packages were in developer preview so this is potentially subject to change.

Answer (score 2):

Angular's `effect` doesn't allow to listen for a particular property change.

Like @Eliseo said, you can achieve that by leveraging rxjs:

```
toObservable(mySignal)
   .pipe(
      pairwise(), 
      map(([oldValue, newValue]) => { ... })
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

`  public historicValue : any = []
public messageAlert = false;

```
public countEffect = effect(()=>{    
 this.historicValue.unshift(this.counterPrueba());
  if(this.historicValue.length > 1){
    this.alert = `El contador ${this.historicValue[1]} se ha modificado a  ${this.counterPrueba()}`
    this.messageAlert = true;
  }
```

});`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).